# AWSCognito Missing region in config error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using the `aws-sdk javascript` in my back-end and I can use `AWS` fine but when I try to use the `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` method I get a `"Missing region in config error"` as a response.

```
var config = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: "MYACCESSKEY", secretAccessKey: "MYSECRETYKEY", region: 'us-east-1'
});

var params = {
  IdentityPoolId: 'MYIDENTITYPOOLID', /*   required */
  Logins: { /* required */
    "login.my.myapp": 'string',
    /* anotherKey: ... */
  },
  IdentityId: null,
  TokenDuration: 0
};

cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params,function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else console.log(data);               // successful response
});
```

In the docs it said that:

> By default, credentials and region settings are left unconfigured. This should be configured by the application before using any AWS service APIs.

So I set my region but why am I still getting an error?

Comment: **See Also**: [Configuring region in Node.js AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31039948/1366033)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting the region in a local `config` variable. It should be set in the global `AWS.config`, like this:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
```

The same applies for the credentials. In case you want to use Amazon Cognito Credentials for all your AWS clients, you should initialize `AWS.config.credentials` like this:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'YOUR_POOL_ID'
});
```

I hope this helps!