# Configuration Error: Missing Region in Config (AWS)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, region, aws-sdk-js

I am getting a configuration error when I run my node application. The error is:

```
{ ConfigError: Missing region in config
at Request.VALIDATE_REGION (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:12027:47)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:11804:22)
at callNextListener (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:11794:14)
at C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-
sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:12021:11
at finish (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-
sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:10842:9)
at Config.getCredentials (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:10887:9)
at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:12016:28)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:11800:20)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:11776:12)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\chris\Documents\AWS API 
TEST\myapp\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js:13792:16)
message: 'Missing region in config',
code: 'ConfigError',
```

The code I have is:

```
//Authenticate AWS:
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2a:"Identity Pool ID"'});
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
          credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2a'
});
```

This is running on an express server using ejs and node. I am using the Amazon JavaScript SDK.

I attempted the solution here:

> [AWSCognito Missing region in config error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976202/awscognito-missing-region-in-config-error)

This did not help.

**EDIT 1:**

As requested Below, I have attacheed full code:

```
var express = require('express');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var EC2 = require('aws-ec2')('access key', 'secret');
var scale = require('aws-scale');
var router = express.Router();

//Authenticate AWS:
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:b0efe3c7-e4c9-420f-836b-6d776e2a9271'
}); 

var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});

AWS.config = myConfig

var minInst = 1;
var maxInst = 3;

var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
//Set up parameters for EC2 Instances:
var params = {
  ImageId: 'ami-6e1a0117',
  MaxCount: minInst,
  MinCount: maxInst, 
  InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: 'terminate',
  InstanceType: 't2.micro',
  Monitoring: {
    Enabled: true 
  },
  NetworkInterfaces: [{
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: true,
    DeleteOnTermination: true,
  }],
  Placement: {
    AvailabilityZone: 'us-west-2',
  },
  SecurityGroupIds: [
    'sg-b0307ccd',
  ],
  SecurityGroups: [
    'CAB432Assignment2SG',
  ],

};
ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err, err.stack); //An error occurred
  }
  else{
    console.log(data); //Successful Response
  }
});
```

Comment: **See Also**: [Configuring region in Node.js AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31039948/1366033)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct code of **Oregon** region is `us-west-2`.You have set it as `us-west-2a` in two places.

While mentioning identity pool id,correct the code as below and try:

```js
AWS.config.update({region:'us-west-2'});
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:"Identity Pool ID"'
});
```

If you are not passing the ***region*** for the API *CognitoIdentityCredentials*, then it will pull the data from *AWS.config*.

Also, In your code, while initializing *AWS.CONFIG* with ***region*** name, You have used `us-west-2a`. Correct it, if you are going to use it ***instead of AWS.config.update***.

```js
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
    credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});
```

### Update

I have identified another issue. The issue is that, you are initializing the *AWS.config* with `var myConfig = new AWS.Config()` but you are ***NOT updating*** the *AWS.config* class back with it. The missing code is : `AWS.config = myConfig`.

As you are not updating it back and also you are not updating the existing default class using `AWS.config.update({region:'us-west-2'});` as well, it throws the `Missing region in config` error.

#### Correct Code snippet

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:identity-pool-id'
}); 
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
    credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});
AWS.config = myConfig
```

Comment: I have corrected it but I still get the same error.

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood I have updated the answer section.

Comment: I am now getting the error: `missing credentials in config` When I scroll down, it says `message: 'XMLHttpRequest is not defined'`. I have copied your corrected solution into my code. The only thing I changed was my identity pool id.

Comment: It does not seem to get this error wen I comment out the request to start an EC2 machine.

Comment: Well that's surprising!! Am able to request new EC2 instance successfully. Both the ***config initialization*** and ***ec2.runInstances()*** code blocks are in same .js script right? Can you attach your whole code?

Comment: Ok I will add it now.

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood I am not getting `missing credentials in config` error code with your code as well. The only difference is that I only retained `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');` and removed the other imports of *express*, *aws-scale* and *aws-ec2* packages. Can you also try that? Maybe `var EC2 = require('aws-ec2')('access key', 'secret');` is causing the issue for you.

Comment: Where is this code entered into what file?

Answer (score 11):

Add region in your config like this:

```js
AWS.config.update({
    region: "REGION" //Here add you region
});
```

Please add it on the very top level (above the line `var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();`)

Comment: When I added this it gave me a credentials error, how would I add credentials to this?

Comment: WHERE is THIS!?
config, there are tons of config files, the CLI has config the project has config the node modules has config>
There is no line "var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();"

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are correct.
However, for `aws-sdk-js-v3` you can't set `AWS.config` globally.
Thus the workaround would be:

```js
process.env.AWS_REGION = 'us-west-2'
```

Also if you're getting error about unreachable `"169.254.169.254:80/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/"` during you CI build, you might want to set fake credentials in a same way:

```js
process.env.AWS_REGION = 'us-west-2'
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'test-key'
process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'test-secret'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's the order of execution (that's why side effects are bad).

Wrong:

```
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:b0efe3c7-e4c9-420f-836b-6d776e2a9271'
}); 

var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});
```

Correct:

```
// update the config
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});

// then create the instance
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:b0efe3c7-e4c9-420f-836b-6d776e2a9271'
});
```