# How to configure the region in the AWS js SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-regions

## My problem

I am writing a simple js function that reads some information from AWS CloudWatch Logs.

Following the answer at [Configuring region in Node.js AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039948/configuring-region-in-node-js-aws-sdk), and the [AWS nodejs SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#describeLogGroups-property), I came up with the following:

## Code

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();

console.log(AWS.config.region)              // Undefined

AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1'          // Define the region with dot notation
console.log(AWS.config.region) .            // eu-central-1

AWS.config.update({region:'eu-central-1'}); // Another way to update
console.log(AWS.config.region) .            // eu-central-1


var params = {
  limit: 0,
//   logGroupNamePrefix: 'STRING_VALUE',
//   nextToken: 'STRING_VALUE'
};

// This call is failing
cloudwatchlogs.describeLogGroups(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

## Output and error

```js
undefined
eu-central-1
eu-central-1
{ ConfigError: Missing region in config
    at Request.VALIDATE_REGION (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:91:45)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at callNextListener (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
    at /Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:85:9
    at finish (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:315:7)
    at /Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:333:9
    at SharedIniFileCredentials.get (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:126:7)
    at getAsyncCredentials (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:327:24)
    at Config.getCredentials (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:347:9)
    at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (/Users/adam/binaris/adam-test-sls/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:80:26)
  message: 'Missing region in config',
  code: 'ConfigError',
  time: 2017-07-11T09:57:55.638Z } ...
```

## Environment

The code is running locally under `node v8.1.2`.

## My question

**How can I correctly configure the region in the AWS js SDK?**

## Addendum

Opened [an issue on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1622#issuecomment-317837779) and got some response.

Comment: This problem persists across the SDK. SQS and Cloudsearch also require region and the SDK docs leave it out.

Comment: **See Also**: [Configuring region in Node.js AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31039948/1366033)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or, alternatively, you can specify that when creating your cloudwatch object:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({region: 'eu-central-1'});
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. The AWS js documentation examples are misleading and counterproductive.

Answer (score 5):

> Write code in following way it will work.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// assign AWS credentials here in following way:
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'asdjsadkskdskskdk',
  secretAccessKey: 'sdsadsissdiidicdsi',
  region: 'eu-central-1'
});
var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({apiVersion: '2014-03-28'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following.

```
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-central-1'});
```

You can find more information in following link.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work - I've tried it in my code.

Comment: Strange. Getting the same output or different output?

Comment: Same, because this line already appears in my code. See above.