# Where can I find the list of region string for AWS services, e.g.: s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've read this question about region string.
[Configuring region in Node.js AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039948/configuring-region-in-node-js-aws-sdk)

But I tried all the possible pages in Amazon Console, and still couldn't find the region string to use for initializing service object.

Below is S3 manage console where it shows region, but I need exact region string for initializing s3 object. I can not use "US East (N. Virginia)"

[image]

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01', 
  region: 'us-east-1',  // where can I find this string???
  accessKeyId: 'AKIAJTZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
  secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})
```

I am trying to find document where I can map 'US East (N. Virginia)' to 'us-east-1'. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) has a listing of all regions.

It is currently:

- Asia Pacific (Mumbai): ap-south-1
- Asia Pacific (Seoul): ap-northeast-2
- Asia Pacific (Singapore): ap-southeast-1
- Asia Pacific (Sydney): ap-southeast-2
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo): ap-northeast-1
- Canada (Central): ca-central-1
- EU (Frankfurt): eu-central-1
- EU (Ireland): eu-west-1
- EU (London): eu-west-2
- South America (São Paulo): sa-east-1
- US East (N. Virginia): us-east-1
- US East (Ohio): us-east-2
- US West (N. California): us-west-1
- US West (Oregon): us-west-2